# Difficult to remember the functions defined in PHP due to no return type defined in the code

Tags: php

I find it hard to remember the function declaration or functions in PHP. First, if I have a function like "getElementsByTagName()". If I code this in Java, I will write down the full return type and the type of the parameters.. i.e

```
DOMNodeList nodelist =  dom.getElementsByTagName ( string "name" )
```

By coding like this, I will remember the return type is DOMNodeList and only call function in DomNodeList.

In PHP, the type is omitted in the code.

```
$dom = document.getELementsByTagName("tag");
```

Is there a way to include the type implicitly in the code so I won't forget it. I would like to remember the parameter type and the return type of the function that I am calling.

Thanks

Comment: Note that in Java 10, even Java won't require you to write the type every time you declare a value. In a dynamically typed language, you usually solve this problem by writing unit tests (and frequently running them!).

Comment: Thanks Justinas and Daniel for helping with my question.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use proper IDE that show you function return type on hover or other way. (PHPStorm, Eclipse or [others](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/482-best-php-ide-of-the-year-comparison.html))
2. Use PHP docs to indicate return type:

```
/**
 * @return MyObject
 */
function execute() {return new MyObject;}
```

3. Use proper methods/functions names to indicate what's going on. Like `function getMyObject()`
4. Use PHP 7 new feature [return type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations):

```
function getMyObject(): MyObject {}
```

5. Buy some medicine/vitamins to improve your memory.